# Как оператор вычитания запускает преобразование массива в число?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, числа

Мне не понятно как в этом примере массив преобразуется в число.

```js
console.log(10 - [4]); //6
```

Насколько я знаю, при попытке преобразования операнда к примитивному типу данных запускается либо `toString()`, либо `valueOf()`. По умолчанию `valueOf()` возвращает сложный тип данных, а `toString()` преобразовывает сложный тип данных к строке. Как, к примеру, это происходит здесь:

```js
console.log([4] + 10); //"410"
```

Как в первом примере массив мог преобразоваться в число, если по умолчанию `valueOf()` возвращает массив?

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае, массив преобразовывается в строку `"4"`. (Массив превращается в строку состоящую из значений массива, разделенных запятой).
Так как далее идет вычитание числа из строки, то данная операция преобразовывает операнды в числа, так как операции вычитания нет для строк. Собственно потому у тебя и получается `10 - 4`.

Во втором случае, массив преобразовывается так же в строку `"4"` и при сложении, JS воспрнимает это не как математическое сложение, а как конкатенацию строк, потому второй операнд превращает так же в строку, в итоге получается `"4" + "10"`, что приводит к такому результату.

Answer (score 2):

Если уж лезть в дебри стандарта, то в обоих случаях применяется абстрактная операция [`ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator).

В первом случае (вычитание) на 5 шаге к массиву применяется абстрактная операция [`ToNumeric`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-tonumeric), которая сначала приводит массив к примитиву ([`ToPrimitive`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-toprimitive)) (в случае с массивом получится строка `'4'`), а потом полученную строку приведёт к числу операцией [`ToNumber`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-tonumber).

Во втором случае (сложение) срабатывает шаг 2 и получается конкатенация строк как раз потому что примитив от массива это строка.